# WTP HTTP Preview server - How can I re-configure default server port?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

Under Eclipse Ganymede how can I re-configure the default server port (8080) of the Eclipse WTP "HTTP Preview Server"?

@Leonel

I suppose you never saw the "view" linked to this question, I asked "HTTP Preview Server", not other server views where the port is *obviously* visible between any other settable option ;-) otherwise I would not have asked on StackOverflow if the real problem was only to search between form settings

@Leonel

Tnx for your reliability, it's not a common virtue in these days ;), in fact as read I'd like to know if there is some hidden configurable param :p

Answer (score 47):

HTTP and J2EE Preview servers can be used as well, but as you have
discovered, there isn't any UI to change the port used if there is a
conflict. However, you can change it manually.

1. Go into your workspace directory and open the file `.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\servers.xml` into a text editor or using `File > Open File...` in Eclipse.
2. Find the `<server>` element for the Preview server in question and add a `port` attribute, e.g. `port="8181"`.
3. Restart Eclipse to pickup the change.

Comment: Tested this and it works on Indigo, mind blowing that this option isn't available in the UI.

Comment: This still works in Kepler.  (Odd it hasn't been patched into the UI yet though.)

Comment: It works on Neon too, however, if you edit server configuration in UI, the port option is lost.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to change the port for one server configuration, try this: open the configuration double-clicking the desired server on the list of servers (menu option `Window/Show View/Servers`)? There is a group named `Ports` with a list of ports. I think you want to change `HTTP/1.1` (to edit it, click the port number. And dont forget to `CTRL+s` to save it. ;)
EDIT:
First, sorry for the lazy reponse. You was right (kinda). I saw it but never used it. I use Jboss, Tomcat or Jerry as server. I created an HTTP Preview and noted that there inst a port to configure.

I ran my server test and eclipse complains

And looking at the [help page](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/thttppreview.html) you notice that you can change it:

> The HTTP Preview server is a Hypertext
>   Transfer Protocol (HTTP) embedded test
>   server that is integrated with the
>   workbench. It is intended for
>   preliminary testing and saves you time
>   to download, install, and set up an
>   HTTP server. However, as your static
>   Web project progresses through its
>   development cycle you are encourage to
>   test and run on an external HTTP
>   server. You can use the HTTP Preview
>   server as a convenient way to check
>   for errors before you do a final test
>   on an external HTTP server.

So, i think you cant do it. :(

Comment: I suppose you never saw the "view" linked to this question, rember I asked "HTTP Preview Server", not other server views where the port is between any settable options  ;-) otherwise I would not have asked on StackOverflow for searching on tabs

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse menus , Go to window->show view--> servers

when you get list of server in server tab double click on the server that you have and change the port number manually.

Hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: HTTP Preview Server has virtually no options in the eclipse ui.

Comment: The question is about the HTTP preview server, not servers in general.

Answer (score 0):

Open Your .metadata where your project is stored on your workspace.
brows upto the file path 
.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\servers.xml

open the file servers.xml and in server tag add the attribute port = "any port number".
example:
server.xml