# Problem with "Dynamic web project" - Web preview server is not starting

Tags: java

I have RAD(Rational Application Developer) version 9.00. I have created a "Dynamic web project" and I want test it using "Web preview server" which is already listed under available run times.

I tried run my application
using **Run As -> run on server**
and selected the "**web preview server**" from the existing server list.
When I clicked finish after about 30 seconds below mentioned message was shown.

```
Starting web preview server" has encountered a problem.
 Server Web Preview Server was unable to start within 30 seconds. If the 
 server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

Below mentioned log messages were displayed in console:

```
Launching defaultServer0 (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130510-0831) on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.6.0_02-b06 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer0 has been launched.
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for security-1.0
[ERROR   ] CWWKO0221E: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint initialization did not succeed.  The socket bind did not succeed for host * and port 8080.  The port might already be in use.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications.
```

any idea what I am doing wrong here? Regards

Comment: It seems that the port 8080 is already in use. Either make sure that it is not (by stopping the application currently listening on port 8080) or choose another port.

Comment: How do I check which application is using port 8080?

Comment: [`netstat -ab` on windows (as administrator)](https://superuser.com/q/707249/1079262) and [`netstat -lp` on linux](https://www.tecmint.com/find-out-which-process-listening-on-a-particular-port/)

Comment: Port 8080 is in use the process "[tnslsnr.exe]" is using it, how can I change port for web preview server?

Comment: [WTP HTTP Preview server - How can I re-configure default server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/741871/10871900)

Comment: I added attribute port="8181" for web preview server and restarted the rad IDE but error is still the same...